Wiremock ignores mutipart/form-data matchers
In my tests, I want to mock external API (Twilio). I have the following mapping config for Wiremock (version 3.8.0, run as Docker container):
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "priority": 1,
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json",
        "multipartPatterns": [
          {
            "matchingType": "ANY",
            "bodyPatterns": [
              {
                "matches": ".*should-fail.*"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 500,
        "jsonBody": {
          "error": "cannot send"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "priority": 2,
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
          "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "api_version": "2010-04-01",
          "body": "foo bar baz",
          "date_created": "Mon, 22 Jul 12:00:00 2024 PT",
          "date_updated": "Mon, 22 Jul 12:01:00 2024 PT",
          "date_sent": "Mon, 22 Jul 12:02:00 2024 PT",
          "direction": "outbound",
          "from": "+1 888 000 1111",
          "messaging_service_sid": "MG0d229447d086b7bc8a63b4be7de0f050",
          "sid": "SM12ababababab12abababab",
          "status": "sending",
          "to": "+1 123 123 1234"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

When I'm sending the following request:
POST http://localhost:8081/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 57
User-Agent: IntelliJ HTTP Client/PyCharm 2024.1.4
Accept-Encoding: br, deflate, gzip, x-gzip
Accept: */*

To=%2B1+123+123+9999&From=%2B18880001111&Body=should-fail

Wiremock, for some cosmic reason, constantly matches the later mapping and responds with:
{"account_sid":"ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","api_version":"2010-04-01","body":"foo bar baz","date_created":"Mon, 22 Jul 12:00:00 2024 PT","date_updated":"Mon, 22 Jul 12:01:00 2024 PT","date_sent":"Mon, 22 Jul 12:02:00 2024 PT","direction":"outbound","from":"+1 888 000 1111","messaging_service_sid":"MG0d229447d086b7bc8a63b4be7de0f050","sid":"SM12ababababab12abababab","status":"sending","to":"+1 123 123 1234"}

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 27ms (27 ms); Content length: 419 bytes (419 B)

Here is the request journal:
{
  "requests" : [ {
    "id" : "51e64e51-52af-46ef-b086-3c8eb8032767",
    "request" : {
      "url" : "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json",
      "absoluteUrl" : "http://localhost:8081/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json",
      "method" : "POST",
      "clientIp" : "192.168.65.1",
      "headers" : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-Length" : "57",
        "User-Agent" : "IntelliJ HTTP Client/PyCharm 2024.1.4",
        "Accept-Encoding" : "br, deflate, gzip, x-gzip",
        "Accept" : "*/*",
        "Host" : "localhost:8081"
      },
      "cookies" : { },
      "browserProxyRequest" : false,
      "loggedDate" : 1721656632388,
      "bodyAsBase64" : "VG89JTJCMSsxMjMrMTIzKzk5OTkmRnJvbT0lMkIxODg4MDAwMTExMSZCb2R5PXNob3VsZC1mYWls",
      "body" : "To=%2B1+123+123+9999&From=%2B18880001111&Body=should-fail",
      "protocol" : "HTTP/1.1",
      "scheme" : "http",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "port" : 8081,
      "loggedDateString" : "2024-07-22T13:57:12.388Z",
      "queryParams" : { },
      "formParams" : {
        "To" : {
          "key" : "To",
          "values" : [ "+1 123 123 9999" ]
        },
        "From" : {
          "key" : "From",
          "values" : [ "+18880001111" ]
        },
        "Body" : {
          "key" : "Body",
          "values" : [ "should-fail" ]
        }
      }
    },
    "responseDefinition" : {
      "status" : 200,
      "jsonBody" : {
        "account_sid" : "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "api_version" : "2010-04-01",
        "body" : "foo bar baz",
        "date_created" : "Mon, 22 Jul 12:00:00 2024 PT",
        "date_updated" : "Mon, 22 Jul 12:01:00 2024 PT",
        "date_sent" : "Mon, 22 Jul 12:02:00 2024 PT",
        "direction" : "outbound",
        "from" : "+1 888 000 1111",
        "messaging_service_sid" : "MG0d229447d086b7bc8a63b4be7de0f050",
        "sid" : "SM12ababababab12abababab",
        "status" : "sending",
        "to" : "+1 123 123 1234"
      }
    },
    "response" : {
      "status" : 200,
      "headers" : {
        "Matched-Stub-Id" : "3629754a-3ff0-4ece-bdd5-e2315c1589fa"
      },
      "bodyAsBase64" : "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",
      "body" : "{\"account_sid\":\"ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",\"api_version\":\"2010-04-01\",\"body\":\"foo bar baz\",\"date_created\":\"Mon, 22 Jul 12:00:00 2024 PT\",\"date_updated\":\"Mon, 22 Jul 12:01:00 2024 PT\",\"date_sent\":\"Mon, 22 Jul 12:02:00 2024 PT\",\"direction\":\"outbound\",\"from\":\"+1 888 000 1111\",\"messaging_service_sid\":\"MG0d229447d086b7bc8a63b4be7de0f050\",\"sid\":\"SM12ababababab12abababab\",\"status\":\"sending\",\"to\":\"+1 123 123 1234\"}"
    },
    "wasMatched" : true,
    "timing" : {
      "addedDelay" : 0,
      "processTime" : 0,
      "responseSendTime" : 0,
      "serveTime" : 0,
      "totalTime" : 0
    },
    "subEvents" : [ ],
    "stubMapping" : {
      "id" : "3629754a-3ff0-4ece-bdd5-e2315c1589fa",
      "request" : {
        "url" : "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json",
        "method" : "POST"
      },
      "response" : {
        "status" : 200,
        "jsonBody" : {
          "account_sid" : "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "api_version" : "2010-04-01",
          "body" : "foo bar baz",
          "date_created" : "Mon, 22 Jul 12:00:00 2024 PT",
          "date_updated" : "Mon, 22 Jul 12:01:00 2024 PT",
          "date_sent" : "Mon, 22 Jul 12:02:00 2024 PT",
          "direction" : "outbound",
          "from" : "+1 888 000 1111",
          "messaging_service_sid" : "MG0d229447d086b7bc8a63b4be7de0f050",
          "sid" : "SM12ababababab12abababab",
          "status" : "sending",
          "to" : "+1 123 123 1234"
        }
      },
      "uuid" : "3629754a-3ff0-4ece-bdd5-e2315c1589fa",
      "priority" : 2
    }
  } ],
  "meta" : {
    "total" : 1
  },
  "requestJournalDisabled" : false
}

I already tried changing matchers, like contains, or other matching types (i.e., bodyPatterns) but with no luck.
Side note: Tests are in the Python app, so using the Java SDK is not an option for me.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The form you're sending in the request (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) isn't multipart.
To match attributes of this type of form you need to use the formParameters element e.g.
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json",
    "formParameters": {
      "myFormElement": {
        "matches": ".*should-fail.*"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 500,
    "jsonBody": {
      "error": "cannot send"
    }
  }
}

